# Java Runtime Error

Tags: java, runtime

I am using the following code to try and retrieve information from the Windows Task Manager:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist /v /fi");
```

When I enter "tasklist /v /fi" into windows CMD it works, but in java it gives me the error that the file path could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use String array to run command with multiple options.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"tasklist","/v","/fi"});
```

Comment: Like this: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"tasklist/v"}); because I have tried that and I still get the error.

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing I am creating the String Array as follows: String[] tempString = new String[]{"tasklist", "/v ", "/fi ", "\"Imagename eq javaw.exe"\""}; in the last part I need Imagename eq jawax.exe surrounded with "" (Quotation Marks) the code I am using isn't doing it though.

Comment: Yes the last paramater is: Imagename eq javaw.exe. all together the problem is I need it to be surrounded by "" quotation marks for the cmd to read it and the code I am using is suppose to do that but it is not.

Comment: Can you try single quots?

Comment: Hi, ok I figured it out. The code I posted in the comments worked.